# How to convert XBRL file to DOM

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xbrl

How to convert XBRL file to JAVA Objects.

- do we have any open source JAVA API?
- Is JAXB parsing technique appropriate for this conversion ?

Comment: You can give a try with [xbrlcore](http://xbrlcore.sf.net) The last revision is not completely stable though, you can try with tag 0.2.2

Comment: Xbrl ia just XML, so you can use any XML parser, like jaxb, but due to its complexity, an xquery capable parser, like Saxon will be more useful

Comment: @BillVelasquez. Yes, Bill You are right, I need a parse like Saxon. Thanks for the update ..but I m looking for an open source library. I tried with xbrlapi but not getting any meaningful solution.

Comment: @Seki, Thanks for the information.  do we have any JAVA implementation using this xbrlcore API which can be useful to parse XBRL file?

Comment: BaseX is an Open Source XML database built on Java, with XQuery support, that you can embed in your applications. Take a look to http://basex.org

Answer (score 0):

use maven. put files into resources

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/tr/gov/turkiye/einvoice/eledger</schemaDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>

            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```